# Real-time video(image) stitching

Tags: image, video, image-stitching

I'm thinking of stitching images from 2 or more(currently maybe 3 or 4) cameras in real-time using OpenCV 2.3.1 on Visual Studio 2008.

However, I'm curious about how it is done.

Recently I've studied some techniques of feature-based image stitching method.

Most of them requires at least the following step:

1.Feature detection
2.Feature matching
3.Finding Homography
4.Transformation of target images to reference images
...etc

Now most of the techniques I've read only deal with images "ONCE", while I would like it to deal with a series of images captured from a few cameras and I want it to be "REAL-TIME".

So far it may still sound confusing. I'm describing the detail:

Put 3 cameras at different angles and positions, while each of them must have overlapping areas with its adjacent one so as to build a REAL-TIME video stitching.

What I would like to do is similiar to the content in the following link, where ASIFT is used.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5OK6bwke3I

I tried to consult the owner of that video but I got no reply from him:(.

Can I use image-stitching methods to deal with video stitching?
Video itself is composed of a series of images so I wonder if this is possible.
However, detecting feature points seems to be very time-consuming whatever feature detector(SURF, SIFT, ASIFT...etc) you use. This makes me doubt the possibility of doing Real-time video stitching.

Comment: Did you ever get anything working?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzDpMsVgjxg

Comment: I used this service with great success. http://unbouncepages.com/panoslide/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have worked on a real-time video stitching system and it is a difficult problem. I can't disclose the full solution we used due to an NDA, but I implemented something similar to [the one described in this paper](http://vmv09.tu-bs.de/downloads/papers/ada09.pdf). The biggest problem is coping with objects at different depths (simple homographies are not sufficient); depth disparities must be determined and the video frames appropriately warped so that common features are aligned. This essentially is a stereo vision problem. The [images must first be rectified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_rectification) so that common features appear on the same scan line.

Comment: I'm currently writing my codes on Visual Studio 2010. My professor told me to develop it on PC first and of course it's almost impossible to be real-time. So far I've just done feature detection and matching using OpenCV 2.3.1. The result is that it takes almost 3 seconds to finish the steps (feature detection(SURF) and matching, including removing outliers using RANSAC) and the frame rate is very very terrible...

Comment: My prof. will have someone to realize it on FPGA o I have to finish all the necessary algorithms first and later on to let someone to realize it on FPGA cuz I'm not familiar with it.  I was just thinking to implement the feature-based image stitching methods to do this.  That is, to put them in a infinite loop "while (True)" to continuously do image stitching of 2 or 3 images taken from 3 different cameras.

Comment: Also, thank you for your reply of course.  I just thought that my question would be too dumb to be seen :(.

Answer (score 5):

You might also be interested in my project from a few years back. It's a program which lets you experiment with different stitching parameters and watch the results in real-time.

Project page - https://github.com/lukeyeager/StitcHD

Demo video - https://youtu.be/mMcrOpVx9aY?t=3m38s

Comment: Very nice demo videos, is it really easy to run the project?

Comment: do we need to run it on visual studio?